# Nodejs request-promise error when sending POST request?

Tags: node.js, request

When I attempt to send a post request, using the request-promise module installed via npm I receive an error and I cannot figure out why.

I have tried removing parts of the options and header but to put it straight I am simply stuck.

```
    function sendData() {
        var options = {
            method: 'POST',
            uri: `http://www.myurl.com/placeholder.json`,
            body: {
                "data":"desiredData"
            },
            headers: {
                "Accept": "application/json",
                "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate",
                "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.9",
                "Connection": "keep-alive",
                "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
                "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest"
            }
        }
        rp(options)
            .then(function (parsedBody) {
                console.log(parsedBody)
            })
            .catch(function (err) {
                console.log(err)
            });
    }

sendData();
```

A post request should be sent and log the returned json but instead I receive the following error:

```
_http_outgoing.js:654
    throw new errors.TypeError('ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE', 'first argument',
    ^

TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The first argument must be one of type string or Buffer
    at write_ (_http_outgoing.js:654:11)
    at ClientRequest.write (_http_outgoing.js:629:10)
    at Request.write (C:\Users\ninja_000\Desktop\TronJS\node_modules\request\request.js:1500:27)
    at end (C:\Users\ninja_000\Desktop\TronJS\node_modules\request\request.js:549:18)
    at Immediate.<anonymous> (C:\Users\ninja_000\Desktop\TronJS\node_modules\request\request.js:578:7)
    at runCallback (timers.js:756:18)
    at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:717:5)
    at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:697:5)
```

Comment: If my answer was useful to you, you can accept it or qualify it so other users with a similar problem can find a solution faster.

Answer (score 0):

try changing content type

```
function sendData() {
    var options = {
        method: 'POST',
        uri: `http://www.myurl.com/placeholder.json`,
        body: {
            "data":"desiredData" // this should be a JSON format if you are using 
                                //application/json
        },
        headers: {
            "Accept": "application/json",
            "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate",
            "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.9",
            "Connection": "keep-alive",
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest"
        }
}

rp(options)
    .then(function (parsedBody) {
         console.log(parsedBody)
    })
    .catch(function (err) {
         console.log(err)
    });
}
```

Comment: Didn't seem to help

Comment: try removing the whole header meta details. let it choose defaults and try again

Answer (score 0):

In error message it says about a argument error, so check the body part of your code in `sendData()` function.

try this,

```
function sendData() {
    var options = {
        method: 'POST',
        uri: 'http://www.myurl.com/placeholder.json',
        body: {
            data:'desiredData'
        },
        headers: {
            "Accept": "application/json",
            "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate",
            "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.9",
            "Connection": "keep-alive",
            "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
            "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest"
        }
    }
    rp(options)
        .then(function (parsedBody) {
            console.log(parsedBody)
        })
        .catch(function (err) {
            console.log(err)
        });
}
```

I edit 6th line of your code.

Answer (score 0):

I created this example so that the functioning of `request-promise` is understood.

Set `option.body` to your data and `json: true` to encode the body as JSON.

I use a simple online fake REST API server, so you can run the example without changing anything.

```
const rp = require('request-promise');
function sendData() {
  var options = {
    method: 'POST',
    uri: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts',
    body: {
      title: 'foo',
      body: 'bar',
      userId: 1
    },
    headers: {
      "Content-type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8"
    },
    json: true // Automatically stringifies the body to JSON
  };

  rp(options)
    .then((parsedBody) => {
      console.log(parsedBody);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err);
    });
}
sendData();
```

Comment: I now receive this,

Comment: \node_modules\request\lib\querystring.js:43
  return str.replace(/[!'()*]/g, function (c) {
             ^

TypeError: str.replace is not a function
    at Querystring.rfc3986 (C:\Users\ninja_000\Desktop\TronJS\node_modules\request\lib\querystring.js:43:14)

Comment: at Request.json (C:\Users\ninja_000\Desktop\TronJS\node_modules\request\request.js:1293:30)
    at Request.init (C:\Users\ninja_000\Desktop\TronJS\node_modules\request\request.js:406:10)
    at Request.RP$initInterceptor [as init] (C:\Users\ninja_000\Desktop\TronJS\node_modules\request-promise-core\configure\request2.js:45:29)
    at new Request (C:\Users\ninja_000\Desktop\TronJS\node_modules\request\request.js:127:8)
    at request

Comment: (C:\Users\ninja_000\Desktop\TronJS\node_modules\request\index.js:53:10)
    at Timeout.ATC [as _onTimeout] (C:\Users\ninja_000\Desktop\TronJS\tron.js:112:5)
    at ontimeout (timers.js:458:11)
    at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:296:5)
    at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:259:5)

Comment: That error is because you are not following the example correctly, you are altering the body of the request. @Ogden

Comment: @Ogden If my answer was useful to you, you can accept it or qualify it so other users with a similar problem can find a solution faster.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix it, at first I added `json: true` under the headers which then lead to another error posted above. To solve this I also had to change the content type to `application/json` thanks to everyone that helped.

Comment: Those suggestions were in my response you could accept or qualify please.

Answer (score 0):

data:'desiredData' should be data: desiredData where desiredData is a json object. For instance:

```
var desiredData = { propertyName: propertyValue }
```